# Mobx state updating in console log, but not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I've created a MobX store (React Native project) and am updating a state value on button click. The state is successfully updating as displayed in a console log, but the DOM is not re-rendering with the updated state.

Most answers on SO are a little outdated as they recommend adding `@observable` in the right places, but the latest MobX docs say to use a different syntax with `makeAutoObservable(this, { key: value })`.

(**EDIT**: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-yalow-2e2mc?file=/src/Home.js) so you can see in Home.js the console logging on button press, but "You love..." not updating with mobx store value)

Here's my current set up:

store.js

```
import { makeAutoObservable, observable } from "mobx";

export class ChooseTea {
  tea;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this, {
      tea: observable,
    });
  }

  selectTea = (tea) => {
    this.tea = tea;
  };
}
```

Home.js

```
import { ChooseTea } from "../data/store";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

export const Home = observer(() => {
  const store = new ChooseTea();

  const handleChildChoose = (tea) => {
    store.selectTea(tea); // value passed to store
    console.log(store.tea); // successfully logs the new chosen tea
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>You love {store.tea}</Text> // does not update on new tea chosen
      <View style={styles.teaCardContainer}>
        {teaData &&
          teaData.map((teaObj) => (
            <TeaCard
              id={teaObj.id}
              teaData={teaObj}
              key={teaObj.id}
              strength={teaStrength * 2}
              handleChoose={handleChildChoose}
            />
          ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});
```

TeaCard.js

```
function TeaCard({ teaData, handleChoose }) {
  const handleClick = (tea) => {
    handleChoose(tea); // value passed to parent component (Home.js)
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{teaData.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <Rating count={teaData.rating} />
      <Button
        title="Choose"
        onPress={() => handleClick(teaData.name)}
        color={AppStyles.colour.secondary}
       />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

`const store = new ChooseTea();`

You are recreating you store on every render. Your component actually react to changes, starts rerendering, but then new store is created and `tea` is not selected there by default. So you are changing data in your old store, but then use data from newly created one.

What you can do is use `useState` or `useMemo` for your store, like that:

`const [store] = useState(() => new ChooseTea());`

You also need to define all your properties, it won't work otherwise (or at least without [extra configuration](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations)):

```
export class ChooseTea {
  // Use null or empty string "", for example
  tea = null;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  selectTea = (tea) => {
    this.tea = tea;
  };
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions66634911-yi0vy?file=/src/Home.js)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried both your suggested `useState` syntax and also `const store = useMemo(() => new ChooseTea(), []);`, but sadly neither one worked. Any idas?

Comment: You probably made some mistake! Could you provide Codesandbox example?

Comment: Oh, I see, you also need to define properties with something, they cannot be empty/undefined (at least without extra configuration) https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations I will update my answer!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!